# fill dynamic array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I am setting up a method in **C++** called fill_array, that takes `a.fill_array(1)` and fills the array. Could someone please explain why I'm getting an error?

```
class DynamicArray{
public:
    int * array = malloc(sizeof (int) *n); 
public:
    DynamicArray(){
        *array = new int[a+1];
        cout <<"  " << endl;

    }
    fill_array(int x){
        array.fill(x);
    }
int main()
{
    DynamicArray a(9);
    a.fill_array(1);   /* fills array with consecutive #’s */
    a.print_array();
}
```

I am getting an error that says that:

```
request for member ‘fill’ in ‘((DynamicArray*)this)->DynamicArray::array’, which is of non-class type ‘int*’"
```

Comment: Your code as posted contains a lot of compiler errors but to address the one you're asking about, the line `array.fill(x)` appears to be attempting to call a `fill` member function, but `array` is not an object with any such member function, it is a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: Please, have a look at [`std::fill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill). And, btw. why `new []`? Why not `std::vector`? I assume that's a requirement of assignment but you should state this in question.

Comment: What is `n`?  Please provide a [mre].